# How many men's singles matches have ended with the same score in all five sets?

Tags: trivia, tennis

How many men's singles Grand Slam matches (or Davis Cup matches) have ended with the same score in all five sets? Like the 2002 Wimbledon QF where David Nalbandian defeated Nicholas Lapentti 6-4, 6-4, 4-6, 4-6, 6-4.

Comment: Technically, they don't. Nalbandian has 6 in sets 1 & 2, but 4 in set 3... :p I know what you meant. Decent trivia question, well done.